# Is there a Remote Desktop Connection manager for mac that will connect to Windows machines?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, eclipse

I am managing 4 Windows VM's on a network for running tests. I would like a Remote Desktop Connection manager that makes it easy to connect and switch between network machines.

I am due for a hardware upgrade, and would like to switch to a Mac for a variety of reasons, but being able to manage my RDP sessions easily is a must.

Free software is a plus.

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a hardware/software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request. - From Review

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Remote Desktop from the Mac App Store may work for you. Lots of VNC client/servers out there too. RealVNC for example. You can use Apple's built-in Screen Sharing app to connect to 3rd party VNC servers running on your Windows PC. Just do a Command-K to connect to server and enter vnc://address.

Comment: I'd also check out the new Beta version of MS RDC, the occasional bug but mainly better than the current release. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/

Answer (score 2):

Check out Royal TSX if you're after a full featured connections manager that can do RDP as well as other protocols like, VNC, SSH, Telnet, etc.

https://www.royalapplications.com/ts/osx

It's also free for small environments (up to 10 connections and credentials).

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the mentioned product.

Answer (score 0):

The best remote desktop program I've found (and I've been through them all) is Splashtop Remote. It's completely cross platform, cross device and only your connection limits it's speed. On decent broadband it's flawless. Bets part is that it will also play the audio from the target device and all the functionality (mouse clicks, keyboard, even gestures in some cases) can be used from the remote. I hate subscription apps, but this one I cannot live without.